# Create a reusable code for autocompletion of a date textbox based on another textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are lots of date fields in my application for which i need to autocomplete the second date textbox based on the value entered in the first textbox. Example:

```
<td class="mytddata">
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="mytextbox" runat="server" ID="txtYellowCreationDate" Text='<%# Bind("YellowCreationDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' TextMode="Date" OnTextChanged="UpdateExpirationTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
<td class="mytddata">
   <asp:TextBox CssClass="mytextbox" runat="server" ID="txtYellowExpirationDate" Text='<%# Bind("YellowExpirationDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
```

The way i autocomplete the expiration textbox in this case is using "OnTextChanged" event and in the code behind :

```
protected void UpdateExpirationTextBox ()
{
     txtYellowExpirationDate.Text=myCal.AddYears((DateTime)txtYellowCreationDate.Text,2).ToString();
}
```

I'm looking for ways to write this code once and reuse it for the other cases which require such autocomplete. I thought of creating a user control that contains these two textboxes and use it each it's required in my pages, however I wasn't able to "Bind" the field values from the main page to the fields in the user control, but i will have to write much code to do it.

Any ideas or suggestions to achieve this or do i have to rewrite the code each time this feature is required ?

Comment: Would front-end code (javascript) be an alternative ? That would help. Are you also completely sure you need both field each time ? Cause, I mean, if you anyway copy data from one field to another each time the first one changes, you could basically just use the value of the first field...

Comment: I'm not sure if  this will work since the IDs of the controls will vary so i will have to rewrite the function for each set of dependent dates. Also yes i need the two fields, the first date is the creation date of a card and the second it's its expiration date which needs to be visible to the user

Comment: If you need to display it and it's not actually an input, then you for sure shouldn't use an input field. From where I see it  doing it front-end might be a solution, you can select items to trigger an event based on any attributes, not only ID, so you could for example base the behaviour on the same class that you give all these inputs then search for the closest let's say `span` element and update its content with the related expiration date. That could also be done server-side though with  a similar approch to yours, but we'll need more explanation on your trials and what failed...

Answer (score 0):

Write code as a javascript function, and ref the script throughout your project wherever needed. If all textbox autocompletes need to share the same information, pass the information that needs to be shared between textboxes back to the server (good candidate for Ajax calls if needs to be done "on the fly").